# RFT: Facing problem while recording while using Mozilla

Tags: automated-testing, java, test-strategy, rft

Facing issue while recording using [RFT](https://www.ibm.com/bs-en/marketplace/rational-functional-tester) in `Mozilla Firefox` browser.

Not able to enable environment for `Mozilla`, even after installing `RFT` enabler for `Firefox`.

Getting errors like:

```
Record resume pause failed. no script insertion point defined.
Record stop failed (CRFCN0779E: Script being recorded cannot be saved)
```

Please, suggest me solution and the procedure how to enable `Mozilla` along with all versions of `java` used.

Answer (score 1):

Because of Firefox having trouble with Java and Java not wanting to anymore support applets in Java, we noticed trouble testing web applications in Firefox with RFT. However, with the latest RFT fixpack (8.6.0.9), it seems that its functional again.

In addition, now there is no need to either enable the browser or the JRE! This leads to significant improvements. I would encourage you to try the latest version and report your findings.